# Eclipse - List of default keyboard shortcuts

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a list of the default Eclipse keyboard shortcuts?  I'm generally looking for language agnostic things like starting the debugger or deleting an entire line in the source editor.

Comment: Did you check Google first?  Tons of links on the topic - http://bit.ly/4FgqrN

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Rather than a *full* list of shortcut ([JGlass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7221628/jglass) mentions for Eclipse 4.6 [this pdf](https://github.com/pellaton/eclipse-cheatsheet/raw/master/eclipse4.6/eclipse-shortcuts-4.6.0.pdf)), I prefer using only a few shortcuts:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>: "Show Key Assist", List of shortcuts (depending on the context)

[image: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tips/images/key-assist.png]

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>: Quick Access

[image: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-QqHaeh1yJDU/Tsoc0bZmaSI/AAAAAAAABVg/WzNyqfmRmXE/s1600/Eclipse+Quick+Access+now+shows+keybindings+for+commands.png]
<sup>Source: "[Good features of Eclipse 3.6 (Eclipse Helios) JDT, 2011, from Sony Thomas](http://tips4ufromsony.blogspot.fr/2011/11/good-features-of-eclipse-36-eclipse.html)"</sup>

Those two covers almost everything.

You can add two others:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>: Quick Fix

[image: http://depth-first.s3.amazonaws.com/20080111/list_options.png]

- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>: [Plug-in Spy](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/spy/index.php)

[image: http://www.willianmitsuda.com/wp-content/uploads/eclipse_tips/spy_opentype.gif]

---

Note that [Eclipse 2019-09](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/platform.php#show-keybinding) now shows key bindings when command is invoked.

> For presentations, screen casts and learning purposes, it is very helpful to show the corresponding key binding when a command is invoked.
>   When the command is invoked (via a key binding or menu interaction) the key binding, the command's name and description are shown on the screen.
>   Key binding of triggered command shown on screen

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/images/show_key_bindings.png]

> You can activate this in the Preferences dialog via the Show key binding when command is invoked check box on the `General > Keys` preference page.
>   To toggle this setting quickly the command '`Toggle Whether to Show Key Binding`' can be used (e.g. via the quick access).

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about this one!

Comment: At these times, the `Ctrl`+`Shift+`L` shortcuts has the same binding of `Quick text search`, that is a really faster way to search for text. 
From [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quick-search-eclipse):
Ctrl+Shift+L shows Quick Search; Ctrl+Shift+L twice shows list of shortcut; Ctrl+Shift+L 3 times shows Preferences > General > Keys

Comment: The link #3 is broken, e.g. http://www.techvj.com/misc/blog_images/eclipse_qaccess/eclipse_qaccess.jpg  I tried to find a trace of the image to replace it but cannot.  Also tried to edit the article to too many linked non https images (now a requirement) however I did find this nifty list [eclipse-shortcuts-4.6.0.pdf](https://github.com/pellaton/eclipse-cheatsheet/raw/master/eclipse4.6/eclipse-shortcuts-4.6.0.pdf)

Comment: @JGlass Thank you. I have replaced the image by a new one, and included your link in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 26):

As VonC said you can get alist of short cuts with the following command.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> "Show Key Assist", List of shortcuts (depending on the context)

**SHORTCUTS FOR DEVELOPMENT**

But here are some which you will use often during your development.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> Switch between openning and closing braces.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> Open any file quickly without browsing for it in the Package Explorer. This shortcut opens a dialog box that accepts the name of the file you’re looking for.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Open a type (e.g.: a class, an interface) without clicking through interminable list of packages. If what you want is a Java type, this shortcut will do the trick.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> Go directly to a member (method, variable) of a class file, especially when there are a lot of methods.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Format code.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> Comment out XML or JSP code.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Go to line number N in the source file.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> Show a list of open editors.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> Move between open editors.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> Quick Fix.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> Quick Access.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> Go to the last edit location.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Go to a supertype/subtype.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> Indent selected code block.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> Move to one problem (i.e.: error, warning) to the next (or previous) in a file.

<kbd>F3</kbd> Go to a type declaration.Alternatively, you can hold Ctrl down and click (ie: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>) the hyperlinked variable.

**SHORTCUTS FOR VARIABLE GENERATION**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>  Generate return value type and variable assignment

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Generate return value type and variable assignment. but here you can make selections.

**SHORTCUTS FOR DEBUGGING**

<kbd>F8</kbd> Resume

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> Resume.

<kbd>F5</kbd> Step Into

<kbd>F6</kbd> Step Over

<kbd>F7</kbd> Step Return

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> Run to Line.

<kbd>F11</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> Debug

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> Toogle Break Point

You can find further shortcuts under : 
Help → Help Contents → Java Development User Guide → Reference → Menus and Actions

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer not quite correct as in Eclipse you can redefine keyword shortcuts (as I often do).

You can always access current list of defined shortcuts by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in Eclipse (on Windows at least).

Comment: Questioner asked for "defaults"

Answer (score 1):

The **full** list of defaults in Eclipse 4.6 and earlier versions can be obtained from this GIT Hub page:
https://github.com/pellaton/eclipse-cheatsheet specifically https://github.com/pellaton/eclipse-cheatsheet/raw/master/eclipse4.6/eclipse-shortcuts-4.6.0.pdf