# Eclipse shortcut for commenting jsp, xml code

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In IDEA, we can comment/uncomment lines in java as well as html,jsp, xml files with the same keyboard shortcut combination. I tried doing that in eclipse but was not able to comment out lines in html,jsp and xml files. Is there a way to do it in Eclipse? Also I would like to know whether bulk comment is also available for non-java files.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to **Add Block Comment** in both XML and JSP files (works at the line level or for a selected block).

Just in case, if you are looking for a particular shortcut, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to **Show Key Assist** (i.e. the Commands and their Bindings).

Comment: +1. "Show Key Assist" is good advice ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986195/eclipse-list-of-default-keyboard-shortcuts/1986236#1986236

Comment: +1. And if you don't like to key binding showed in Show Key Assist, open Preferences/General/Key, and set your own...

Comment: @zoltán-ujhelyi Actually, in my Eclipse installation the default binding didn't work in JSP editor (even thoughs its scope was 'In Dialogs and Windows'), so I had to copy it and set When = JSP Source.

Comment: short key for this comment - "<%-- commented --%>" ?

Answer (score 47):

I believe <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works in XML, not sure about JSP.  I think it lacks consistency in the various editors, and some don't have this shortcut.

Comment: this hotykey is much more better that upper one

Answer (score 24):

I found <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> works in JSP too, it works like:

```
<tiles:insertDefinition name="" >
</tiles:insertDefinition>

<!--<tiles:insertDefinition name="" >-->
<!--</tiles:insertDefinition>-->
```

add comment tag line by line, and select the sentences, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> again can toggle remove the comments.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> add block comment in JSP, works like:

```
<tiles:insertDefinition name="" >
</tiles:insertDefinition>

<!--<tiles:insertDefinition name="" >
    </tiles:insertDefinition>                       
-->
```

can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> to remove the block comment.

PS: I want to find out, which eclipse shortcut can add/remove `<%-- --%>` comment in JSP?

Answer (score 7):

In eclipse they use same kind of shortcut to do this which is for:

I found <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> works in XML and JSP.

**Single line**

*comment* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

*uncomment* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

**Multiline**

*comment* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

*uncomment* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> (note the backslash)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't work for me on XML files. ctrl+shirt+c works.

Answer (score 2):

In Mac, for xml:

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> - To comment a line or selected block of lines

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> - To uncomment a line or selected block of lines

This works in Eclipse Photon (4.8.0)