# Navigating menus in Eclipse without moving my hands

Tags: eclipse, key-bindings

If you're as lazy as I am, you don't want to go moving your hand every time you need a menu in Eclipse.  Is there any way to navigate menus in Eclipse without moving your hands to the mouse or the arrow keys?

I've searched for key bindings for menu navigation (replacing Up/Down/Left/Right), but came up empty.

UPDATE
To clarify, I am familiar with a lot of the features mentioned in the answers, such as "Show Key Assist", and "Quick Access".  I've found that the only time I'm ever really moving my hands is to navigate through a list of items, such as the Package Explorer or the Open Resource dialog.  I haven't found any alternatives to the arrow keys for these actions.

Comment: Are you talking about menus or views?

Answer (score 2):

I like to bind ["Show Key Assist", and "Quick Access"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986195/eclipse-list-of-default-keyboard-shortcuts/1986236#1986236) to convenient keys, in order to get a list of all menus/commands/views accessible *from the context I am currently in*.

This isn't really a replacement from <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>arrows</kbd>, but it can help reduce the menu exploration you need to do in order to find the right action to launch.

Answer (score 0):

As @VonC mentioned, I'd use Quick Access (CTRL+3) for most commands that don't already have a keyboard shortcut.

You can also use mnemonics to access most menu items.  i.e. ALT+F P for print, or ALT+R N for the Run Configurations dialog.

F10 will open the left most menu on most OSes.  CTRL+F10 will open the view menu from within a view, and the ruler menu in a text editor.  SHIFT+F10 will open a context menu in almost all locations.

PW

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate between views of eclipse, you can use Ctrl+F7 & then up/down arrow keys to select the one. For 'Open Resource Dialog', you can use Ctrl+Shift+R.