# Eclipse: Can You Hit A KeyBinding To Find The Command It Is Bound To?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm new to Eclipse.   Is it possible in Eclipse to hit a keybinding and find the name of the command it is bound too?

For example,  pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and have something like "open-dialog" come up in a list telling me that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is bound to the command "open-dialog".

Comment: See [Eclipse - List of default keyboard shortcuts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986195/eclipse-list-of-default-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: I read that post, it doesn't answer my question.  I want to push a shortcut and get the name of a command it is bound to, in a particular instance of Eclipse...not generally ( ie someone changed some keybindings, I want to know what the new command is ).

Comment: I don't think there is any remade solution to your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows > Preferences > General > Keys

You can TYPE ( not press ) the name of the keys, it will sort the list by the name of the keys

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Eclipse doesn't make this easy. (Related note: IntelliJ IDEA does.) There are a few things that might help you out, though:

1. In the Eclipse settings for key bindings, you could do "Export to CSV". Then you can search that document for key combinations.
2. Also in the Eclipse settings for key bindings, you can sort the "Binding" column. The list is unwieldy to scroll through, but the ordering of multi-key combinations seems to be well defined so you could eventually find the key combination you're looking for.
3. If you want to look up a common command without going into the settings, you can assign a keyboard shortcut to "Show Key Assist". You can't sort the list by key combination, but it's at least a relatively short list to look through.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the original wording,

> pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and
> have something like "open-dialog" come up

it sounds like the *Show key binding when command is invoked* -> *Through keyboard* option in the *Keys* preference page would at least partially do what you're looking for:

[image: Screenshot of Keys preference page]

This will bring up a toast-like overlay each time you press a key combination that's associated with a command. It will show the command name and a more detailed command explanation, if available.

However, the overlay will only display for a few seconds and then disappear, i.e. an onlooker might miss it if they are distracted by other activities on the screen. I don't think that there is a way to display this information "in a list", i.e. in a more permanent fashion, but I think that this would be a great feature to help developers learn new keyboard shortcuts in a pair programming environment.