# In IntelliJ IDEA, how do I find the command associated with a particular keyboard shortcut?

Tags: intellij-idea

I was trying to find a way to map the action that closes the current active split (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Escape</kbd>) to a custom keybinding, but I was unable to find it in the settings, because all of the words I associated with it were incorrect (It was "Hide Active Tool Window"). I eventually found it by running through all the possible actions until I saw the one associated with the keybinding I knew worked.

I found [an associated Eclipse question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327769/eclipse-can-you-hit-a-keybinding-to-find-the-command-it-is-bound-to/) that mentions that finding commands associated with shortcuts is easy to do in IntelliJ, but doesn't mention how to do it. How do I either search the current keymap for a specific key combination, or press a key combination to get the name of the associated action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **Find Shortcut** button in the Keymap settings dialog, put the focus inside the field and press the shortcut, it will find the action bound to this shortcut:

[image: find shortcut]

Answer (score 0):

You can search `Keymap` in the `Settings`, the search box is on the left-top corner in the `Settings`.

Comment: I can search keymap if I know the name of the /action/ -- I'm asking what to do if I don't, and only know the key combination.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may have a plugin that has overridden some keystroke, which doesn't show up in the `Preferences | Keymap`.

If this is true, then the only way you I've found to find it is to disable your plugins one by one, until you see which plugin was overridding the keystroke.

This happened to me recently when a plugin mapped `<`, which of course made it impossible to type lots of code!