# How to go to the specific line in Eclipse editor?

Tags: eclipse, notepad++

In notepad++, ctrl+g asks the line number to enter. In the same way how to go to the specific line in Eclipse editor?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986195/eclipse-list-of-default-keyboard-shortcuts , and you can look at your keybindings as described [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Faccessibility%2Fkeyboardshortcuts.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+l  Jump to Line Number. To hide/show line numbers, press ctrl+F10 and select 'Show Line Numbers'