# Why can't I copy code from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I've created a code and I'm trying to copy it, I don't know why but I can't copy text. not from the code nor the console.

I tried using Cmd+C and also double-click and "Copy", both of them aren't working.
I can copy using other softwares.

I now noticed that I can paste into the editor but can't copy from the editor.

I have MacBook Air with Mac OS X Yosemite and Eclipse Luna 4.4.1, thank you.

Comment: seems to be a known bug in some environments: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=368354

Comment: I couldn't find there the solution.. Also I now noticed that I can paste into the editor but can't copy from the editor.

Comment: Maybe key is wrong assigned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986195/eclipse-list-of-default-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: @PeterMmm It's not a problem with the key, I said I tried using also double-click and "Copy"..

Comment: Having the same problem now.  Did you ever resolve this?