# Why does eclipse shutdown on a keypress in a keyboard layout?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When using a Nepali Traditional Keyboard Layout and pressing the '[' or the Shift+[ key, eclipse shuts down unexpectedly. This affects the exported plugins also.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986236/4831083) it might be of some assistance

Comment: The shortcuts are not defined in the eclipse preference. This only occurs with the specific keyboard layout.